# Execute multiple spring batch jobs concurrently with different parameters

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-batch

I have one spring batch job configured which run inside an spring webservice. The job has a few steps. I have deployed two instances of this webservice in different tomcats (but both instances uses the same mysql database).

I would like to run a spring batch job concurrently in both tomcats (one in each one) with different parameters. I am not using partioning and the paramaters for each job are completely different.

I start the job in one of the tomcats and everything looks fine. But when I start a second job in the second tomcat, the job is created but it did not start, not even execute the first line od code of the first step.

I am not an expert using spring batch, so maybe I am doing something wrong. But if the spring batch job is running in two separate tomcat instances, they should run in parallel no?

This is the job configuration:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans 
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-3.0.xsd">

        <job id="uploadProjectDataJobNormal " xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
            <step id="setupProject" next="loadReferenceBuilds">
                <tasklet ref="projectSetupTasklet"/>
                <listeners>
                    <listener ref="promotionListener"/>
                    <listener ref="snpAwareStepListener"/>
                    <listener ref="snpAwareItemReadListener"/>
                </listeners>
            </step>

        <step id="loadReferenceBuilds" next="snpToMorph">
            <tasklet>
                <chunk reader="faiReader" processor="faiProcessor" writer="faiWriter" commit-interval="100"/>
            </tasklet>
            <listeners>
                <listener ref="promotionListener"/>
                <listener ref="snpAwareStepListener"/>
                <listener ref="snpAwareItemReadListener"/>
            </listeners>
        </step>

        <step id="snpToMorph" next="indelToMorph">
            <tasklet>
                <chunk reader="snpReader" processor="snpProcessor" writer="snpWriter" commit-interval="100"/>
            </tasklet>
            <listeners>
                <listener ref="promotionListener"/>
                <listener ref="snpAwareStepListener"/>
                <listener ref="snpAwareItemReadListener"/>
            </listeners>
        </step>

         <step id="indelToMorph">
            <tasklet>
                <chunk reader="indelReader" processor="indelProcessor" writer="indelWriter" commit-interval="100"/>
            </tasklet>
            <listeners>
                <listener ref="promotionListener"/>
                <listener ref="snpAwareStepListener"/>
                <listener ref="snpAwareItemReadListener"/>
            </listeners>
        </step>
<listeners>
            <listener ref="snpAwareBatchJobListener"/>
        </listeners>
</job>
```

This is how I start the jobs:

this.jobLauncher.run(this.uploadProjectDataJobNormal, jobParameters);

The job paramaters have certain parameters which are unique between the two jobs like a date, name of the element which I want to upload.

The job repository and launcher are configured in the next way:

> ```
> /**
>  * Job repository.
>  * 
>  * @return the job repository.
>  * @throws Exception in case the job repository could not be created.
>  */
> @Bean
> public JobRepository jobRepository() throws Exception {
>     JobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
>     jobRepositoryFactory.setDataSource(this.persistenceConfig.dataSource());
>     jobRepositoryFactory.setTransactionManager(this.persistenceConfig.transactionManager());
>     jobRepositoryFactory.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_DEFAULT");
>     return jobRepositoryFactory.getJobRepository();
> }
>
> /**
>  * Job launcher.
>  * 
>  * @return the job launcher.
>  * @throws Exception in case the job launcher could not be created.
>  */
> @Bean
> public JobLauncher jobLauncher() throws Exception {
>     SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
>     jobLauncher.setJobRepository(this.jobRepository());
>     jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(this.taskExecutor());
>     return jobLauncher;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Task executor.
>  * 
>  * @return the task executor.
>  */
> @Bean
> public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
>     SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor ex = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
>     ex.setConcurrencyLimit(1);
>     return ex;
> }
> ```

**UPDATE:** One solution I thinked about is create a second job declaration with another name like "uploadProjectDataJobNormal2". Will that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end the solution was simple than expected. Change the concurrency to 2 in the job launcher:

```
ex.setConcurrencyLimit(2);
```

My believe was that will not affect if the spring batch jobs are running in differents JVM, but it does.